# Construct a Javascript Template and inserting values into it

Tags: javascript

If anybody knows , please help me , i am very badly struck .

From  AJAX Call i am constructing  this data in my server (This data is fetched from the server so there can be any number of such rows data )

```
{data:[{one:"1",two:"2"},{one:"3",two:"3"}]}
```

My question is that , is it possible to construct a similar array inside javascript dynamically ??

For example , depending upon the number of rows , i want to construct a similar jaavscript array dynamically 
(For example depneding on data.length , i want to construct this type dynamically

```
var data = {
  jobs:[
    {one:"1",two:"2"},
    {one:"3",two:"3"}
  ]
};
```

Please help me .

Answer (score 1):

This will dynamically create a list of dictionary, which is what I think you are looking for:

```
var row = {};
row['one'] = "1";
row['two'] = "2";
data.push(row);
row = {};
row['one'] = "3";
row['two'] = "3";
data.push(row);
// outputs [{"one":"1","two":"2"},{"one":"3","two":"3"}]
alert( JSON.stringify( data ) )
```

Comment: The above one is static , i want to create it dynamically , anyways thanks for your time .

Comment: for ( var i = 0; i < data.jobs.length; i++) {
      
   jsonDatarav = '{ '
                  + '"one" : '
                  + '"' + data.jobs[i].one + '"'
                  + ", "
                  + '"two" : '
                  + '"'+ data.jobs[i].two + '"'
                  + ' }';
       
    
  }   , but this is only creating one value of data only

Comment: Notice that you are building an array [].  You are manually constructing a JSON a string.  My method used JSON.stringify to build the array of dict.  If you wish to use your string method, then you need to start 'data' with data='[', construct your row data+=jsonDatarav", append it to 'data', construct and append more to data+=',' data+=jsonDatarav and terminate with date+=']'.  Otherwise, use the JSON.stringify method above.